# redirect input in command line

Tags: redirect, command-line-arguments

I am not really getting the redirect input in DOS mode.

I know the working example: sort < list.txt
which sorts the content of my list.txt

but why doesn't this work:
dir < arguments.txt
the content of my arguments.txt file is for instance just: -D

I would expect the command 
dir < arguments.txt
be equal to
dir /D

why isn't this working?

thanks
juergen

Answer (score 0):

The < operator redirects console input to be from a file.  The cooresponding > operator redirects the console output to be to a file.

The sort command reads the console until it reaches end of file (cntl-Z) and then it produces the sorted result.

The dir command does not accept console input, only arguements on the command line, so the the file containing /D is never read.